# How to convert the values in an array to strings and send to php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript file here.What it does is,when a user selects seats accordings to his preference in a theater layout,the selected seats are stored in an array named "seat".This code works fine until function where the selected seats are shown in a window alert.But from there onwards,the code doesn't seem to do anything.

After the above window alert, I've tried to serialize the above array and send it to the "confirm.php" file.But it does not show anything when echoed the seats.

Here is the js code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var settings = {
            rows: 6,
            cols: 15,
            rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
            colCssPrefix: 'col-',
            seatWidth: 80,
            seatHeight: 80,
            seatCss: 'seat',
            selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
            selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
        };

        var init = function (reservedSeat) {
            var seat = [], seatNo, className;
            for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                    if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                        className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }
                    seat.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
                            'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                            '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                            '</li>');
                }
            }
            $('#place').html(seat.join(''));
        };

        var jArray = <?= json_encode($seats) ?>;
        init(jArray);


        $('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)) {
                alert('This seat is already reserved!');
            } else {
                $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
            }
        });


        $('#btnShowNew').click(function () {
            var seat = [], item;
            $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                item = $(this).attr('title');
                seat.push(item);
            });
            window.alert(seat);
        });

        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            var seat = [], item;
            $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                item = $(this).attr('title');
                seat.push(item);
                var seatar = JSON.stringify(seat);
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "confirm.php",
                    data: {data: seatar}
                });
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

Can somebody help me figure it out what's wrong in here?

Comment: can you also show the relevant parts of `confirm.php`? (where you test what you get)

Comment: you actually don't need to stringify the seat array. JQuery will handle that for you.

Comment: @Jeff is right, just send the _seat_ array.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add content type as json.
 `$.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "confirm.php",
           contentType: "application/json" 
           data: {data: seatar}
        });`

For testing you can print `file_get_contents('php://input')` as this works regardless of content type.